# Trigger to set slug before updating row

Tags: mysql

I run the following MySQL code to create the full_contact_social_networks table

```
 CREATE TABLE `full_contact_social_networks` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `base_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(24) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `full_contact_social_networks`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `base_id` (`base_id`);

ALTER TABLE `full_contact_social_networks`
  MODIFY `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

I then want to create a trigger, to set the value of the slug column, to the sha256 of base_id+name. I am using the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER full_contact_social_networksUpd BEFORE UPDATE ON full_contact_social_networks 
FOR EACH ROW SET `slug` = SHA2((CONCAT (`base_id`, `name`)), 256);
```

But this is giving me the following error message:

```
[errno] => 1193
[sqlstate] => HY000
[error] => Unknown system variable 'slug'
```

Comment: Your syntax is off in a number of ways, but more importantly, I don't think you can have a trigger which modifies the same table which called the trigger.  So you might have to find another way to do this.

Comment: try NEW.slug    instead of slug

Comment: It accepts it, if I use NEW, but when I try to update, I get the following error: error #1054 Unkown coumn 'base_id' in 'field list'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Within the trigger body, the OLD and NEW keywords enable you to access
>   columns in the rows affected by a trigger. OLD and NEW are MySQL
>   extensions to triggers; they are not case sensitive.

ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

So your trigger will have to be:

```
CREATE TRIGGER full_contact_social_networksUpd BEFORE UPDATE ON full_contact_social_networks 
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.slug = SHA2((CONCAT (NEW.base_id, NEW.name)), 256);
```

But this only works for updates, you probably want one for inserts as well. In mysql you cannot have a trigger that says INSERT OR UPDATE you need two triggers

```
 CREATE TRIGGER full_contact_social_networksIns BEFORE INSERT ...
```

Comment: This works. I need it for MySQL 5.6, in MySQL 5.7, there seems to be a simpler solution, but MySQL 5.7 is backward compatible